# Index overhead during updates when the property value is unchanged

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

If majority of the indexed properties are not changed during an update to an entity, will there be any difference in performance as compared to the indexed properties having changed? I am trying to understand what kind of hotspotting can happen in an app that has relatively few inserts but a lot of updates where the updates don't change majority of the built-in indexed properties.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any issues with performance by doing updates that don't affect the index.

Hottspotting may happen if you have high read/write rates to a [narrow key range.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range)

On an update intensive application you have to be careful not to update single entities more than once per second because that introduces [higher latency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic#updates_to_an_entity)